# Is it risky to disable SSH passwords?

Tags: ssh, vps, password

This is a very basic question, do bear with me.. I'm setting up a VPS and it seems as though disabling SSH users from logging in with a password is recommended for security.

If I authorize the SSH key for my desktop, what happens if that desktop goes kaput? Won't I entirely lose access to the VPS? If so, it seems like a risky thing to do.

Comment: Ever heard of that magic concept of a backup  for important things like e.g. SSH keys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store your keys somewhere else which is safe, you know - have a backup and don't use keys without a pass phrase.

Make sure that the VPS that you order has out of band access via a console of some description which will allow you to log in via a username/password in the event that ssh is not available.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I have stupidly never thought of backing up SSH keys.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it risky to disable SSH passwords?

No.

---

1. Passphrase your keys.
2. Backup your keys.
3. Use a SSH manager so that you don't have to type the passphrase all the time.
4. Password protect your SSH manager

Answer (score 3):

I have been putting `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on multiple servers. The private key itself is encrypted with a strong password (130 bits of entropy), and the encrypted private key is stored in three different physical locations.

Answer (score 1):

Save you ~/.ssh/ to a secure place (usb stick, cloud,...) and you can reuse the key with a new desktop.